# how to catch \n\r in a filestream and line locations, C#

Tags: c#, pointers, csv, filestream

i have a .CSV file that holds data thats looks like this:

```
Sana Paden,1098,64228,46285,2/15/2011
Ardelle Mahr,1242,85663,33218,3/25/2011
Joel Fountain,1335,10951,50866,5/2/2011
Ashely Vierra,1349,5379,87475,6/9/2011
Amado Loiacono,1406,62789,38490,7/17/2011
Joycelyn Dolezal,1653,14720,13638,8/24/2011
Alyse Braunstein,1657,69455,52871,10/1/2011
Cheri Ravenscroft,1734,55431,58460,11/8/2011
Russ Leth,9720,77542,72705,12/16/2011
```

i am attempting to set up pointers to the lines while reading the data with a Filestream.

1. can i setup pointers to the HDD location of each line the file in C#?
2. i can see how many bytes are in each line but i cannot tell where each line starts...
3. can you determine in the stream itself where each line terminates?

this code does read the file with no issues currently:

```
public static void seeks()
    {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\bussard\Documents\James T work\SourceDatatoedit.csv", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            while ((nextByte = fs.ReadByte()) >= 0)
            {
                Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(nextByte));
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

    }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, but as a general rule here you should ask one question per post. If you need to ask multiple questions, do so in separate posts; you can always link to the first one as being related and containing the data. Using `fs.ReadByte` reads one byte at a time from the file; I'm not sure what a "pointer to the HDD" would be. A line starts at the first character from the file, and continues until it reaches the `\r\n` (not `\n\r` on Windows) combination or `eof`, and the next line (if there is one) starts one byte after the end of the prior line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i wish i could mark both your answers right Darren and Bland because the advise you gave me help me arrive to the answer i was looking for here.  i was able to establish a pointer based system based on where new lines occur.  let me post my code to show you what i did.

```
        public static void seeks()
    {

        long offset = 0;
        string streamsample = "";
        int numoflines = 0;
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\bussard\Documents\JamesTwork\SourceDatatoedit.csv", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            fs.Seek(offset, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
            { //determines how many lines are in my file.
                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    streamsample = sr.ReadLine();
                    numoflines++;

                }// end while block
                Console.WriteLine("Lines: " + numoflines);
            }//end stream sr block

            long[] dataArray = new long[numoflines]; //create a long array based on amount of lines

            fs.Seek(offset, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            StreamReader dr = new StreamReader(fs);
            {create an array of long values based on where new lines occur as pointers.

                numoflines = 0;
                streamsample = "";

                while (!dr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    streamsample = dr.ReadLine();
                    dataArray[numoflines] = offset;
                    offset += streamsample.Length - 1;
                    numoflines++;
                }// end while

                int j = 0;

                while (j < numoflines)
                { // displays the pointer and what data is at that point.
                    fs.Seek(dataArray[j], SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    Console.WriteLine("Pointer: " + dataArray[j].ToString() + " String: " + dr.ReadLine().ToString());
                    j++;
                }//end while
            }//end streamReader dr block

        }//end filestream fs block

    }// end method seeks ()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would assume you mean `\r\n`? For what you are wanting to do, I would assume that you would want something like this

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path))
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
{
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine());
}
```

StreamReader class is good for dealing with text files.

Comment: Yes, i want to be able to determine where each line terminates, then determine the HDD(memory location) and then store that location for fast calling in a generic container like a list....

Comment: does combining the filestream and the StreamReader have more benefits as well?

Comment: can i somehow use a long variable or int to point to any line in the file for quick access?  instead of loading he entire file into memory and then searching for it?

Comment: Yes, you can index based on the position. After you read line, use the Position property, and if you need to load a second time, you can open the stream and call seek to that position.

Answer (score 0):

While reading store the FileStream's [Position](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.position.aspx).  Then use [Seek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.seek.aspx) to navigate to the Position, so you can do your reading at your stored/desired spot.  I would think you would store the amount of bytes along with this position so you can do [Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read.aspx) at this point and not ReadByte again.